# Render problem in Rails form validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, validation, bundler

I'm using rails 2.3.8 with Bundler gem.

I just installed Faker gem (Gemfile), and then suddenly all forms validations errors became like this:

---

```
{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved

There were problems with the following fields:

    * {{attribute}} {{message}}
    * {{attribute}} {{message}}
```

---

It seems that the variables are not printed properly.
What could cause this behavior in Rails?
Where to start to solve the problem, if I need to keep Faker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faker declares a dependency on `i18n`, and it seems that Bundler has helpfully installed it for you.

Unfortunately, the API has changed in the latest version (0.5.0) and is incompatible with the version that comes bundled with Rails 2.3

The most straight forward solution would be to stop using Gemfiles with 2.3 and rely on Faker picking up the bundled version of i18n (which Bundler can't see).

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. It seems that in i18n version 0.5.0 the translation syntax has changed from \{\{key\}\} to %{key}. So for the moment I'm forcing bundler to use version 0.4.2. Hope I won't need any gem with dependency on 0.5.0...